# MYSQL create Function - getting: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, function, procedure

I have created a PROCEDURE using the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE marketingdb_eia.procGetEstateConsumerFromVehicleReg(IN clientId int, IN vehicleReg varchar(10))
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT *, CONCAT(c1.vehicle_reg_1, c1.vehicle_reg_2, c1.vehicle_reg_3, c1.vehicle_reg_4) AS "AllVehicleReg"
    FROM estate_consumer AS c1
      INNER JOIN consumer c2
        ON c1.consumer_id = c2.id
    WHERE c2.client_id = clientId) AS a
WHERE a.AllVehicleReg LIKE vehicleReg;

END //
```

This worked perfectly, so i'm now trying to create a Function for the above, so i was trying to do this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION marketingdb_eia.procGetEstateConsumerFromVehicleReg(clientId int, vehicleReg varchar(10))
RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN

SELECT  *
FROM (SELECT *, CONCAT(c1.vehicle_reg_1, c1.vehicle_reg_2, c1.vehicle_reg_3, c1.vehicle_reg_4) AS "AllVehicleReg"
    FROM estate_consumer AS c1
      INNER JOIN consumer c2
        ON c1.consumer_id = c2.id
    WHERE c2.client_id = clientId) AS a
WHERE a.AllVehicleReg LIKE vehicleReg;

END //
```

But is getting the following error: "Not allowed to return a result set from a function".

After doing a bit of research it looks like you can't return a set which includes columns. I have to use some INTO feature after my SELECT query but have no idea where to do that and what to change to return same values as my PROCEDURE.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can manually build a temporary table, and then call the function, in which you can insert the data into your temporary table。MYSQL seems not to support returning a table